# Nested for loops not resetting python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am new to python and am finding it much harder to work with for loops than in R!

Here is an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


insight_numbers = list(range(379, 397))

insights = ["insight." + str(number) for number in insight_numbers]

#List insight files
folder = ("path\\to\\data")

individual_insight_files = []
for insight in insights:
    individual_insight_files.append(str(folder)  + '\\'+ str(insight) +'.csv')

#Initialize empty lists for use in loops
user_files = []
user_data_list = []

#Outer loop - reads each larger file
for insight in individual_insight_files:
    if not os.path.isfile(insight):
        continue
    try: 
        insight_raw = pd.read_csv(insight)
    except: 
        print(str((insight))) + 'Errored out' 
        continue
    
    ids = insight_raw.PERSON_ID
    
    #Middle loop - identifies user csvs
    for user in ids:
        user_files.append(str(folder)  + '\\'+ str(user) +'.csv')
                
        #Inner loop - puts results of user csvs into list
        for uf in user_files:
            if not os.path.isfile(uf):
                continue
            try: 
                user_file = pd.read_csv(uf)
            except: 
                print(str((uf))) + 'Errored out' 
                continue
            
            print(user_file)
            
            user_data_list.append(user_file)
```

The issue I'm having is that the loop works fine for the first insight file but where the "ids" variable should change with each new insight in the outer loop, it doesn't reset. Sorry I know this is a basic question but I am really stuck! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the contents of each insight file do indeed have different IDs?

Comment: Hi, yes, they have different IDs.

Comment: Then is insight_raw.PERSON_ID not what you want? Print what it is getting each time instead of setting the ids variable. It would be useful to add what you've done to debug to your question/description.

Comment: Expanding on @Sam's comment - you're thinking about for loops correctly, so there must be an error somewhere. Without the data driving your example we can't really help debug. Try simplifying the problem and using print statements to figure out where the issue is occurring. Good luck!